# Unable to load jQuery plugin in systemjs config

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, systemjs

I'm quite new to the systemjs party and I was wondering what I'm doing wrong when loading a jquery plugin inside the systemjs configuration file. The plugin is neither on NPM nor on Github.

```
System.config({
  meta: {
    "vendor/my-plugin/my-plugin.js": {
      deps: [
        'jquery'
      ]
    }
  },
  map: {
    "jquery": "npm:jquery@1.12.1",
    "my-plugin": "path/to/my-plugin"
  }
});
```

Import later on, leads to error:

```
import myplugin from 'my-plugin';
```

I receive `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete config, I believe you are missing configuration of the npm:* subpath. Without it, SystemJS won't know where to fetch the jQuery package. (Check your developer tools to see if it is fetched correctly)

Either try configuring the path to jQuery:

```
System.config({
    ...
    map: {
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery.js"
    }
    ...
});
```

Or, try adding the path to npm-installed packages using a 'paths' wildcard option:

```
System.config({
    ...
    paths: {
        "npm:*": "node_modules/*"
    }
    ...
});
```